# Manipulating HTML using mod_proxy with Apache, e.g. to remove ads

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, man-in-the-middle, mod-proxy-html

For now this is just a technical challenge, but basically I would like to do the following:

**Create a webbased reverse (gateway) proxy using [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [`mod_proxy_html`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) that does not only rewrite HTML urls to match the proxy's hostname, but also rewrites or manipulates the HTML that is being proxied.**

This manipulation on the "man in the middle" gateway proxy would allow one to do all kinds of things, such as:

- remove ads
- translate text from one language to another
- otherwise hack or "improve" the original site

Of course, it could potentially also be used for a lot of bad things, but that is outside the scope of this question.

I know that `mod_proxy_html` parses the original HTML to rewrite all URLs, but does it also allow me to write my own code that will evaluate and manipulate the HTML that is being parsed? Or are there other modules for this?

Alternatively, are there reverse proxies available that can do this? I'm willing to adapt to any language that is suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

By using `mod_rewrite` or `mod_proxy_html` you might be able to do this.

These modules allows you as you probably already know to rewrite/beautify URLs. Instead of altering the *content* of a webpage, which is not the role of Apache, you could alter their *structure* so a link in the received webpage would look like :

```
10.10.1.1/my_secret_injector/alter?url=<the_real_url>
```

Instead of just `<the_real_url>`.

Then implement your algorithm for ads removal or whatever in the language of your choice on the pointed webserver *(10.10.1.1)*.